# Returning a pointer to a deleted object

Tags: c++, class, memory-leaks, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am currently creating a doubly linked list of people and their information.  One of the requirements is to not only delete a person from the list but return a pointer to the person deleted.  I created a `Person*` pointer that can be returned.  At the moment this is done by essentially creating a deep copy and returning the copy while deleting the original.  How can I return this pointer without causing memory leaks?

```
 Person * AddressList::Delete(const char * fname, const char * lname)
{
    bool found = false;
    Node * travel = m_head;
    Node * trail = nullptr;
    Person * retper = nullptr;
    if (m_head != nullptr)
    {
        if (strcmp(lname, travel->GetPerson()->GetLName()) == 0 && strcmp(fname, travel->GetPerson()->GetFName()) == 0)
        {
            found = true;

            retper = new Person(*m_head->GetPerson());
            travel = m_head->GetNext();
            delete m_head;
            m_head = travel;
        }

        else
        {
            while (travel != nullptr)
            {
                if (strcmp(lname, travel->GetPerson()->GetLName()) == 0 && strcmp(fname, travel->GetPerson()->GetFName()) == 0)
                {
                    found = true;

                    retper = new Person(*travel->GetPerson());
                    trail->SetNext(travel->GetNext());
                    delete travel;
                    travel = nullptr;
                }
                else if (travel != nullptr)
                {
                    trail = travel;
                    travel = travel->GetNext();
                }
            }

        }   
    }


    if (found == false)
    {
        cout << "Person not found." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        if (m_head != nullptr)
        {
            trail = nullptr;
            travel = m_head;

            travel->SetPrev(nullptr);

            while (travel->GetNext() != nullptr)
            {
                trail = travel;
                travel = travel->GetNext();
                travel->SetPrev(trail);
            }

            m_tail = travel;
        }
        else
        {
            m_tail = nullptr;
        }

        m_nextR = m_tail;
        m_next = m_head;
        m_length--;
    }

    return retper;
}
```

Comment: you could return unique_ptr, or return a pointer and it is up to the caller to delete it. you need to figure out what the caller expect.

Comment: For my assignment, it is expected for the methods to handle memory leaks.

Comment: well if they want you to return a pointer, one way is to put this pointer in a std::vector<unique_ptr<Person>> deleted_items.
and return the pointer to this. using deleted_items[i].get().

Comment: Why are you creating a new `Person` object? Shouldn't this really just be `retper = m_head->GetPerson()`? (this isn't Java).

Comment: It's your assignment, but I suspect the goal is to delete the list node that the person is in, and return the pointer to the person that was previously held by the node

Comment: I tried doing it that way but the only thing returned is garbage,  The problem is that once I actually delete the person from the list, the 'retper' is also deleted.